Searching for TV series consisting of Police trio team
I am looking for a police drama series starring a trio team consisting of two men and one woman. They deal with normal day to day police work and encounter thugs, drug dealers, murderers and other kinds of criminals. The special thing about the show is that they use stylish motorcycles rather than police cars of bikes. One of the men has a cool dude kind of personality while the other one is more serious. I have seen the show dubbed in Hindi in India 7 years ago on Bindass or on it sister network Bindaas Movies (now called UTV Action). I think it's American but I'm not sure.
There may have been a love triangle between the trio but I'm not sure. I am certain however that one of the men had a relationship with the woman. In one episode, the female lead has a sister or friend which got trapped in drug taking. I think it didn't last long. Does anybody know this show?
Note- There is no supernatural things involved and no hi-tech gadgets/Space Tech etc. Just three police workers (one woman and two men) with motorcycles, all three in main leads.

Might be Super Force or Street Hawk - both were based around motorcycles but I don't remember much else about them.

Was it Police Woman (1974-1978)?

@djmadscribbler both of them not matching the requirement.

@SteB its not a woman oriented show. Your guess is wrong.

@AnkitSharma - Cops on bikes, 2 male characters, light colored! It could be CHiPs http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075488/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1

@FarhanAhmed nopes its not that old

Its Die Motorrad-Cops: Hart am Limit. And below is the pic of the trio police team refereed in the question.

